# Display form fields one at a time in template-django

Tags: python, django

I have set of questions and its answers stored in db.I have a form to get answer for each question.I need to display only one question at a time in template and validate that answer against the original answer stored in db.

For now am able to display one value.But what i need is to display a question in a page and validate if the answer is correct,move on to display next question from db and so on. How do I achieve this?

form.py

```
from django import forms
class details_form(forms.Form):
     answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

views.py

```
def display_question(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print "GET"
        form_class = details_form()
        que_data = details.objects.get(que_id=1)
    else:
        ##POST request
    return render_to_response('sample/display_question.html',{'form':form_class,'que_data':que_data},context)
```

template:

```
{% extends 'sample/base.html' %}

    {% block title %} Question {% endblock %}
    {% block body_block %}   
     <p><strong>Your question : </strong></p>
            "{{ que_data.que }}"
            <p><strong>Type your answer here :<strong></p>
            <form id='details_form' method = 'post' action='/next'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}

                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
                <br></br>
                <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Update:

views.py

```
def display_question(request,question_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    form_class = details_form()
    try:
        quesno_id = {'id':question_id}
        que_data = details.objects.get(que_id=question_id)
    except details.DoesNotExist:
        pass    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = details_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():    
            user_answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
            if que_data.original_answer == user_answer:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("question/%s/" %question_id+1)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        pass
    return render_to_response('sample/display_question.html',{'form':form_class,'que_data':que_data,'quesno_id':quesno_id},context)
```

template

```
{% extends 'sample/base.html' %}

{% block title %} Question {% endblock %}
{% block body_block %}   
       <p><strong>Your question {{ quesno_id.id}} : </strong></p>
        "{{ que_data.que }}"
        <p><strong>Type your answer here :<strong></p>
        <form id='details_form' method = 'post' action="/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            <br></br>
            <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^question/(?P<question_id>\w+)/$',views.display_question,name='display_question'),
)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Songdata(models.Model):
    que_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    que = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    original_answer = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.song_name
```

form.py

```
from django import forms


class details_form(forms.Form):
     user_answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Comment: This is a design question. Design URLS like 'ques/1/' and while processing POST requests increment to the next URL.

Comment: Thanks that helped.Am facing problem in redirecting it to next question.`HttpResponseRedirect("question/%s/" %question_id+1)` whats wrong in this line?. but when I give `<form id='details_form' method='post' action="/Quiz/question/{{ quesno_id.id|add:'1' }}/"`. Its redirecting it to next question but without POST validation. How do i redirect only if the answer to previous question is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an absolute URL path like `HttpResponseRedirect("/question/%s/" % (question_id+1))` (notice the leading slash)

Comment: Tried it giving 404 not found.Do i need to change by form action redirect url?

Comment: Action url should be blank like - action=""

Comment: Problem is with this line `if que_data.original_answer == user_answer:` when I checked.Since its evaluates to False its not redirecting it to next question.But When I traced out both the variables has the same value.I have no clue why it is returning False.

Comment: Then it is a datatype problem. Try if str(que_data.original_answer) == str(user_answer):

Comment: It didn’t work.Included models.py and form.py in my question.

Comment: There were some trailing white spaces.that was the problem.thank you